# How to Generate Custom Image Size in Uploads Folder?

Tags: images

I have an image site which based on Wordpress. There are different resolutions below the picture in single post. For example:

1024*768 - 1200*900 - 800*600

When I click on one of these resolutions the image downloading directly to pc. Also creating these resolutions in wp-content/uploads folder. I want to remove one of these resolutions and add a custom dimension for uploads folder. How to make this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this kind of sites or even worked on it.

You can add custom sizes from your theme's functions.php file using add_image_size(). This may help you https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Based on your requirement I think this would help you too http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-image-crop-sizes/

Feel free to ask any queries.

Answer (score 0):

In you functions.php you need to add the following line;
`add_image_size('NAME',SIZE_WIDTH,SIZE_HEIGHT,HARD_CROP);`
This gives next example;
`add_image_size('new_format',600);`
(The last 2 parameters are optional)

If you already have images in you media library, you need to regenerate the thumbnails.
You can do this with the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/